# Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-code-push

This is the issue after installing `react-native-codepush`.

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-code-push.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :react-native-code-push was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `android/settings.gradle`.

add these lines and you are good to go:

```
********************************************************

include ':app', ':react-native-code-push'
project(':react-native-code-push').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/app')

********************************************************
```

As I wasn't able to find any solution on StackOverflow. So, I thought to write this here.

Here's the original answer: https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1873